# Safari 5 fails to install on my Mac

Tags: mac, safari

I just got the new Safari 5.0 I downloaded because my Mac told me there was a new version that I should be getting.

But when I try to run this new version of the application -- nothing happens! I mean the program seems to be working but nothing appears on the screen and so when I try to see my top sites a little window shows up but it just doesn't show anything. Then 3 seconds later the program shuts down!

I don't know why this is happening; ideas?

- Mac OS X version 10.5.8
- 2.66ghz intel core 2 duo
- 4gb 1067 MHz DDR3

Answer (score 1):

- Do you have `SIMBL` installed? Perhaps there's a plugin that's conflicting with this new version of Safari.
- Delete everything in the `/Users/<YourUserName>/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/` folder
- [Download](http://www.apple.com/safari/download/) and install Safari again and see if the same happens.